# OBIEE 12.2.1.2 COPY data from dashboard - PASTE in excel: wrong order

Tags: export-to-excel, copy-paste, business-intelligence, obiee

when copy pasting data from dashboards (pivot tables; no interactions), sometimes the order in excel is wrong:

I.e.: Dashboard: I have marked a - b ( 1 2 4 5) of a pivot table from left to right and copied them.
[image]

Pasting them into Excel *sometimes* results in:

[image]

Marking C B A (from right to left) and pasting into excel would *sometimes* result in:

[image]

Using the regular obiee export button works fine (always).

Ideas and suggestions are much appreciated - this happens with all browsers.

Comment: So it might be a good idea to use the export button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is so not what you are supposed to do anyways it's not funny anymore. Copy+paste into Excel? Pray tell me why you try to use an analytical system in the first place.

tl;dr : Totally wrong usage of the tool.

Edit: By the way in 11g you couldn't even copy the data that way for security reasons because it's an action that isn't logged anywhere.